# How to match two files and filter a third for matched values by column?

Tags: regex, linux, unix, string-matching

I would appreciate your input on the following:

I want to match two files by there IDs (first column) and filter a third file by columns for only those IDs that match.

I have three files (see below). I would like to match `file1$1` to the IDs in `file2`. Of those IDs that are equal between the two files, I would like to filter `file3` by columns. `File3` columns are ordered similarly to `row1` of `file1`. The only difference is that ID names are not denoted as column names of `file3`. I only know that it has the same ordering.

`file1`:

```
ID  X  Y
ID1 X1 Y1
ID2 X2 Y2 
ID3 X3 Y3
```

`file2`:

```
ID1
ID3
```

`file3` (columns are in similar order as rows of `file1` - only without actual IDs)

```
Z 1 2 3
W 1 2 3
V 1 2 3
```

output:

```
Z 1 3
W 1 3
V 1 3
```

How should I go about?

Comment: Looks like you're just removing the third column from file 3. It's not clear what role the IDs play. Your biggest obstacle is probably not being able to specify the problem precisely in plain language; often, when you're able to do that, code just pops out --- if you know how to code, that is.

Comment: You may use sed command function...

Comment: @ManoloSalsas Sed is a completely silly to use for transformations on data that is organized into rows and columns; the ideal tool for that available in the same environment is Awk.

Comment: you'd be better off combining files 2 and 3 into 1 file, i.e. `paste file2 file3 > newFile2`. Then read about the `join` command. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for sed, awk, paste or join.

```
cut -d' ' -f`grep -nffile2 file1|cut -d: -f1|tr '\n' ,`1 file3
```